# Format double values using a maximum of five total digits, rounding decimal digits if necessary

Tags: java, number-formatting

I have `double` values which I would like to convert to `String` values with the following format restrictions:

> number_of_fraction_digits = max( 0, 5 - number_of_integer_digits )

Essentially I want to keep the number of digits to 5 if possible, rounding decimal digits if necessary. For example:

```
 float          String
-------------------------
     1               1
   100             100
100000          100000
 99999           99999
 99999.99        99999
  9999.99         9999.9
   999.99          999.99
    23.34324        23.343
```

I've looked into using [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/text/DecimalFormat.html) but as far as I can tell it doesn't quite accomplish what I'm after.

It allows setting of the maximum number of decimal digits using `setMaximumFractionDigits()` but as far as I can tell I would have to calculate the number of integer digits and perform the above calculation myself.

So the basic question is whether there is a nice, clean built-in way to format numbers in this way.

Comment: I would say you're truncating/chopping off digits, not rounding.

Comment: Yeah, trucating digits would be fine. eee's answer below gets very close, but `BigDecimal` does something weird with the `999.99` value: rounding it down to `999.98`

Comment: That's an artifact, resulting from the limited precision of float and double numbers. With higher precision, you would see 999.98999 which is as precise as you can get with float. But if you cut away the last 3 nines, you'll end with 999.98.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public class SignificantFormat {

    public static String formatSignificant(double value, int significant)
    {
        MathContext mathContext = new MathContext(significant, RoundingMode.DOWN);
        BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(value, mathContext);
        return bigDecimal.toPlainString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] data = { 1, 100, 100000, 99999, 99999.99, 9999.99, 999.99, 23.34324 };
        for(double d: data){
            System.out.printf("Input: %10s \tOutput: %10s\n", Double.toString(d), formatSignificant(d, 5));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, very clever. I've not worked with [MathContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/math/MathContext.html) before.

When I run the example everything looks great except:

`Input:     999.99  Output:     999.98`

Playing around with the `RoundingMode` to see if there's a simple fix there...

Comment: Probably, it is an implementation bug of rounding down algorithm in MathContext since MS Excel's ROUNDDOWN(999.99; 5) gives 999.99 as you expect

Comment: Also, to add another example which doesn't work quite right: `Input:      234.4  Output:     234.39` Ideally this would be: `Input:      234.4  Output:     234.4`

Comment: That's not a bug. Since 999.99 cannot be represented exactly as a float, the closest value 999.989990234375 is chosen. Rounding down to five significant digits gives 999.98 as expected.

Comment: To follow up on jarnbjo's point, if you move to double values things work as expected: `Input:     999.99  Output:     999.99`. I've edited eee's solution.

Comment: @ulmangt: With doubles, you have exactly the same problem, just with other numbers, e.g. 100.11 will output as "100.10".

Comment: @jarnbjo this is becoming a very interesting problem that needs to be solved ;)

Comment: jarnbjo's comments convinced me the rounding issues aren't a huge deal. Dealing with floating point values it's somewhat inevitable. However, formatting 0.1 with the current solution gives: `Input:        0.1  Output:    0.10000`. I think I can fix it by using `new DecimalFormat( "#.#####" ).format( bigDecimal )` instead of `bigDecimal.toPlainString( )`. It's a little less elegant, but removes the trailing zeros.

Comment: or perhaps using `DecimalFormat fd = new DecimalFormat( ); fd.setGroupingUsed( false ); return fd.format( bigDecimal )` is better (works for different values of the `int significant` argument).

Comment: @eee nice, that's a much cleaner way to get the same effect

Answer (score 2):

eee's answer is much cleaner, and gets almost all the way there. However, I do have a strict requirement to have the number of digits (not including optional decimal point) always be less than a given number (say 5).

*This includes any leading `0.` for an entirely fractional number.*

So:

`Input:   0.111111  Output:    0.11111`

is too long and needs to be:

`Input:   0.111111  Output:    0.1111`

This approach is much less elegant, but is more specific about guaranteeing the final length of the string.

I've posted it here for consideration since it may be the ultimate code that I go with to solve the problem even though it is less elegant.

```
public static String format( double value, int totalDigits )
{
    String s = String.valueOf( value );
    int decimal = s.indexOf( '.' );

    // there is no decimal part, so simply return the String
    if ( decimal == -1 )
    {
        return s;
    }
    else
    {
        int finalLength;

        // example: 23.34324
        // the final result will be length totalDigits + 1 because we will include the decimal
        if ( decimal < totalDigits )
        {
            finalLength = totalDigits + 1;
        }
        // example: 99999
        // the final result will be length totalDigits because there will be no decimal
        else if ( decimal == totalDigits )
        {
            finalLength = totalDigits;
        }
        // example: 999999.999
        // we can't make the final length totalDigits because the integer portion is too large
        else
        {
            finalLength = decimal;
        }

        finalLength = Math.min( s.length( ), finalLength );

        return s.substring( 0, finalLength );
    }
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    double[] data = { 1, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 99999, 99999.99, 9999.99, 999.99, 23.34324, 0.111111 };
    for ( double d : data )
    {
        System.out.printf( "Input: %10s \tOutput: %10s\n", Double.toString( d ), format( d, 5 ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: You are answering your own problem in the good way :) I think you can strip the trailing zeros